# Parking Lot Puzzle

Tags: number-sequence

I have to answer someone urgently but I am not able to find out the answer.[image]

Comment: Hollup, this is not a duplicate, the numbers are different.

Comment: But probably the same concept.

Comment: It doesn't look to me like it's the same. With the other one, once you see what's going on the answer is obvious. With this one, at least for me, applying the idea from the other one doesn't make anything obvious.

Comment: Thought I'd cracked it, reversed the first three numbers would be 81, 411, 851. 81+330= 411+440= 851+550= ....nope that doesn't work haha.

Comment: Is there actually a clear defined answer? For sequence puzzles like these it is possible to make a case for practically any number being correct. How do we know which one is the intended solution?

Comment: The "I have to answer urgently" line lets me assume that the OP does not know the answer, which makes this puzzle rather... bad. Also, the tagging lets one assume it is really *just* about finding the answer to "18,114,158,X,338" which makes it *really bad* and very differnt form the "original" which had some out-of-the-box-but-obvious solution. I'm therefore voting to close unless the post is somewhat improved.

Comment: I remember the original puzzle required you to turn the image upside down. I don't know how it works here

Answer (score 3):

The car is parked in spot

> 274. The difference between 18 and 158 is 140, 158 and 338 is 180. Therefore 114 + 160 = 274

Comment: How do you infer "160" of just two numbers (140 and 180) ? What makes you assume that "+20" is the way to go? It could as well be $* Sqrt(9/7)$..

Comment: (Not saying that your solution isn't "beautiful", but if it is the correct solution, the puzzle is really bad in my eyes.)

Comment: If it's the solution it's also not a very good sequence, as the first two numbers aren't really related, but it got stuck in my head because it was so oddly "neat"

Answer (score 0):

That number might be 294.

It starts with number 18.

18  x  6    +  6    =  114

18  x  8    +  14  =  158

18  x  16  +  6    =  294

18  x  18  +  14  =  338

I here use some sequences.
Also the last digit 4 8 4 8 4 also recursive with my answer.